# Possible to assemble 2D template in 3D, modify and unfold to original state?

Tags: texturing, vector

I am new to blender and would like to know if the following could be achieved. I have a papercraft template in vector format that was designed in a 3D modelling program and unfolded to 2D by someone else, and I would like to make some modifications to the graphics. However to ensure better accuracy it would be convenient to apply the modifications in 3D. Here are the steps I would think to take, but would like some guidance whether this can be achieved, and if so, how I would go about it:

1 - Assemble each piece of the model and piece all the parts together to get the complete model. Somehow curve pieces around to join at either end.

2 - Apply modifications (Importing vector graphics on to the 3D model, and split graphics across parts should they cross)

3 - Unwrap each part to its original state with modifications applied

4 - Export each part in vector format while maintaining the integrity of the graphic (scale, quality etc)

Hopefully I explained well enough what I would like to achieve, any guidance or advice  would be much appreciated.

Thank you :)